# How to check file hash using whirlpool hash?

Tags: c#, cryptography, whirlpool

I wonder how to get whirlpool hash of a file. I can't find the definition for this in HashAlgorithm.

I'm working on a app which will calculate the hash of a file in few known hashing algorithms such as MD5, SHA1, SHA224, etc.

Any ideas?

EDIT. Since I have found [source](http://code.google.com/p/classless-hasher/source/browse/trunk/Hasher/?r=93) it is very complicated to run. Is there any easier solution for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A quick [Google search](https://encrypted.google.com/search?q=C#%20whirlpool) will produce a number of options to explore.

The [Bouncy Castle library](http://www.bouncycastle.org/csharp/) (which has full source code available) offers the Whirlpool algorithm. And [this post on Koders.com](http://www.koders.com/csharp/fidC2A961CC05BA3507428ADCFD823892417F758520.aspx?s=mdef%3a%22abc%22) also includes the full source.